# Unable to Override <NotAuthorized> in Blazor WebAssembly from app.razor

Tags: .net, web, blazor

I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly project and I'm trying to customize the behavior of the  component in my "*Register component*". Somehow I can't overwrite the app.razor given value of NotAuthorized
[image: Code]

Comment: You should also show your code in code blocks, not as screenshots.  See [mre] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have default authorization set anywhere?  You do have some component referencing problems - `CascadingAuthenticationState` should be green, not blue.

Comment: My mistake is simply that i didn't use @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

I thought I had registered that in my _import.razor but guess not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to add the

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization on the component or in _import.razor